# unable to mock httparty request on service module test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, httparty

I'm trying to test the method "get_all_hotels" on my HotelsApiService module:

```
BASE_URI = ENV['HOTELS_API_URI']

def get_all_hotels
    begin
        RequestService.new(BASE_URI).get("/hotels")
    rescue
        "Unable to get service response"
    end
end
```

But can't make the tests pass this point. Apparently the problem is when i want to mock RequestService's call (RequestService is a class that uses HTTParty to perform http requests).

This is the test file:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe HotelsApiService do
  let(:base_uri) { "base_uri" }
  let(:request_service) { double }

  subject { Object.new.extend HotelsApiService }

  before do
    allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('HOTELS_API_URI') { base_uri }        
  end

  describe "#get_all_hotels" do
    let(:api_response) {
      { hotel: { id: 1, name: "Hotel name", address: "Str 34", star_rating: 3, accomodation_type: "hotel" }}
}

    before do
      allow(RequestService).to receive(:new).with(base_uri) { request_service }
      allow(request_service).to receive(:get).with("/hotels") { api_response }
    end

    it 'responds with hotel' do
      expect(subject.get_all_hotels).to eq(api_response.to_json)
    end

  end
end
```

Like this the test returns the following Error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(subject.get_all_hotels).to be_a_kind_of(Hotel)
   #<RequestService (class)> received :new with unexpected arguments
     expected: ("base_uri")
          got: (nil)
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -["base_uri"]
   +[nil]

    Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

And if i try to mock it this other way:

```
before do
  allow(RequestService).to receive_message_chain(:new, :edit).with(base_uri, "/hotels") { request_service }
end
```

I get this other Error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(subject.get_all_hotels).to eq(api_response.to_json)
   #<Double (anonymous)> received unexpected message :get with ("/hotels")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BASE_URI is being set when your source file is loaded, which is before you've mocked ENV to return the value you expect.  Therefore it equals nil and is causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Walpole, I get your point. But where should i mock it then?

Comment: @ntonnelier The way it's written you can't mock it -  To be able to mock it you would need to evaluate it at runtime, something like `RequestService.new(ENV['HOTELS_API_URI']).get("/hotels")`    or if you don't want to access ENV every time you could move the ENV lookup into a class method so that it's only evaluated on first use - which you could then nil out in your tests whenever you wanted to change its value.